# Nested form with complex model fails to create children

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a bit of a complex model association:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessor :roles_attributes
  attr_accessible :roles_attributes, :active, :company_id, :role 
  validates_presence_of :company_id, :role
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :company_id, :message => "Users may only have one role per company."
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :allow_destroy => true 
  has_many :companies, :through => :roles
end
```

The intent here is that a single user (email address) could login under different companies with different permissions (roles) per company.

I have users nested under company and my update controller works fine but now I can't seem to get the new/create controller to work:

Controller:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @role = @user.roles.build.company_id = session[:company_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the View:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for [:company, @user] do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-horizontal">

    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :name_first %>
    <%= f.input :name_last %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :mobile %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :roles, @role do |role_form| %>
        <%= role_form.hidden_field :company_id %>
        <%= role_form.input :active %>
        <%= role_form.input :role, :collection => [ "Guest", "User", "Inspector", "Owner"] %></td>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :notes, :input_html => { :rows => 5, :cols => 70 } %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', company_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form it fails silently except that I notice in the logs that "roles_attributes" is being passed as:

```
"roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"company_id"=>"2", "active"=>"1", "role"=>"Inspector"}}
```

which I think should be:

```
"roles_attributes"=>[{"company_id"=>"2", "active"=>"1", "role"=>"Inspector"}]
```

I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was `has_secure_password`.  I had deleted the password fields and the validation was failing.